# Why does document.write not work?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, document.write

Why does the document.write method not work?

Here's my code:

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE = "JavaScript">

var candidateArray = ['Mr R Green...', 'Ms O Brown...', 'Ms Y Black...', 'Mr G White...', 'Ms B Grey....','Ms I Blue....', 'Mr V Pink....'];
var onlineVotesArray = [21,47,23,11,56,47,30];
var paperVotesArray = [12,4,20,11,5,4,17];

var totalVotesArray;
var x = 0;
var lengthPaperVotesArray = length(paperVotesArray);
for x in range(lengthCandidateArray) {
    totalVotes = onlineVotesArray(x) + paperVotesArray(x);
    totalVotesArray(x) = totalVotes;
    x = x + 1;
}

document.write(totalVotesArray);

</SCRIPT>
```

By the way, I have to use the document.write method and no other variant.

Comment: If you want help, you need to describe what you expected to happen, and what actually happened.  "doesn't work" isn't enough.

Comment: Can you get the error message? `try { 
document.write(totalVotesArray);
} catch (e) { alert(e); }`

Comment: `<SCRIPT LANGUAGE = "JavaScript">` — why are you writing HTML 3.2?

Comment: for x in range(lengthCandidateArray)  What's this?!

Answer (score 4):

Your syntax is all wrong.

To access item in an array, use `[]` not `()`, and `for/in` loop requires parentheses around the expression.

```
 //-v--------------------------------v------parentheses
for (x in range(lengthCandidateArray)) {

    totalVotes = onlineVotesArray[x] + paperVotesArray[x];
 // ---------------v-v-----------^-^------------------^-^-----square brackets
    totalVotesArray[x] = totalVotes;
    x = x + 1;
}
```

Additionally, you're calling `length` and `range` methods. If you don't have them in another script, then they don't exist.

If you simply meant to get the `.length` of the array, use the property. And you don't need a `range` method to loop.

```
var candidateArray = ['Mr R Green...', 'Ms O Brown...', 'Ms Y Black...', 'Mr G White...', 'Ms B Grey....','Ms I Blue....', 'Mr V Pink....'];
var onlineVotesArray = [21,47,23,11,56,47,30];
var paperVotesArray = [12,4,20,11,5,4,17];

var totalVotesArray = [];
var lengthPaperVotesArray = paperVotesArray.length;

for (var x = 0; x < lengthPaperVotesArray; x++) {
    totalVotesArray[x] = onlineVotesArray[x] + paperVotesArray[x];
}

document.write(totalVotesArray);
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/8fkZq/

---

**EDIT::**

If you wanted your output to incorporate the candidates like this:

```
Mr R Green... : 33,
Ms O Brown... : 51,
Ms Y Black... : 43,
Mr G White... : 22,
Ms B Grey.... : 61,
Ms I Blue.... : 51,
Mr V Pink.... : 47
```

...you could change the loop:

```
for (var x = 0; x < lengthPaperVotesArray; x++) {
    totalVotesArray[x] = '<br>' + candidateArray[x] + ' : ' + (onlineVotesArray[x] + paperVotesArray[x]);
}
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/8fkZq/1/

Answer (score 0):

You're referencing "lengthCandidateArray" but this is not defined.

If you opened firebug, you probably would have seen a related error. This is critical information if you ever ask questions in the future.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have some error in your javascript code

```
var totalVotesArray = [];
var x = 0;
var lengthPaperVotesArray =paperVotesArray.length;
for (x = 0;x < lengthPaperVotesArray ; x++){
    totalVotes = onlineVotesArray[x] + paperVotesArray[x];
    totalVotesArray.push(x) = totalVotes;
}
document.write(totalVotesArray.join(', '));//i don't think you can write an array
```

Answer (score 0):

This is riddled with syntax errors. I don't know what languages you're used to programming in, but jScript is clearly not one of them. First off, length(x) is not a global method. If you wanna get the length of an array, you use `array.length`. Next the syntax for for...in in js is `for (x in array) { ... }`. Also, if you want to reference a variable as an array, you have to declare it as such ( `var array = [];` ). Finally, to access the elements of an array, you use `array[x]`, not array(x). Try this instead:

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">

var candidateArray = ['Mr R Green...', 'Ms O Brown...', 'Ms Y Black...', 'Mr G White...', 'Ms B Grey....','Ms I Blue....', 'Mr V Pink....'];
var onlineVotesArray = [21,47,23,11,56,47,30];
var paperVotesArray = [12,4,20,11,5,4,17];

var totalVotesArray = [];
var x = 0;
var lengthPaperVotesArray = paperVotesArray.length;
for (x in paperVotesArray){
    totalVotes = onlineVotesArray[x] + paperVotesArray[x];
    totalVotesArray[x] = totalVotes;
    x = x + 1;
}

document.write(totalVotesArray);

</SCRIPT>
```